# Static Constructors in Background Agents

Tags: audio, background, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In every background audio sample I have found for Windows Phone 7.5/8, I see the following construct, and I would like to know why:

```
private static bool _classInitialized;

public BackgroundAudioAgent()
{
    if (!_classInitialized)
    {
        _classInitialized = true;
        // Other static initialization
    }
}
```

This is a really bizarre way to do static initialization - why not use a static constructor?  I've experimented with using static constructors, and they seem to work without issue, as you would expect.

Despite the apparent uselessness of this style of code, I hesitate to dismiss something that comes from the authors of the audio API.  Is there a reason not to use static constructors in background agents?

Comment: Kind of looks like they're trying to obtain the same behaviour as a singleton class?
Doesn't make much sense otherwise.